# Riddle: When are three equal dates not equal

Tags: .net

Start with three variables, all are System.DateTime.

```
a: 10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM
b: 10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM
c: 10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM
```

Compare them to each other.

```
a=b: True
b=c: True
c=a: True
```

Ok, we have established that all three dates are equal. So when we convert them all to Universal time, we will get the same result. Right?

```
a.ToUniversalTime: 10/2/2009 9:30:00 PM
b.ToUniversalTime: 10/2/2009 9:30:00 PM
c.ToUniversalTime: 10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM
```

So what happened?

Comment: Not enough code, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the value returned by the ToUniversalTime method is determined by the Kind property of the current DateTime object.

- Kind == Utc - no conversion performed
- Kind == Local or Unspecified - conversion is performed according to the local timezone

Answer (score 0):

My bet is it has something to do with c being in a different timezone than a and b.

Comment: Ah, but unlike DateTimeOffset, you can't store the timezone in a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

i agree, c is in different timezone.

```
    Dim a As DateTime = #10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM#
    Dim b As DateTime = #10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM#
    Dim c As DateTime = #10/2/2009 2:30:00 PM#

    If Not (a = b AndAlso b = c AndAlso c = a) Then Stop
    a = a.ToUniversalTime
    b = b.ToUniversalTime
    c = c.ToUniversalTime

    If Not (a = b AndAlso b = c AndAlso c = a) Then Stop
    'reach here no problem, so one of them was in a different timezone
```